# Multiple Ajax posts in a serial manner

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to implement multiple ajax post requests. Suppose there are 3 posts. Then the 2nd post is dependent on the result from the first and the third post is dependedent on the result received from the 2nd post.

How do I place the 2nd ajax post method. Should it be done in the success handler
   jQuery.ajax({
       type : "post",
       dataType : "json",
       url :  ajaxurl,
       data : form_data,

```
   async: false,  
   success: function(response) {
              //2nd ajax post call to be placed here?

      } 
  }       

})
```

//or should 2nd ajax post call  be placed after

I have seen some people also using jQuery.when() but I am not sure whether I could use that. 
Since here I will have to check for when condition 3 times.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

From https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```

a1, a2 being the results returned from the various callbacks?
(This will however execute your three callbacks (async), but return the results of all three)

Otherwise if you've got a dependency from request1 to request2 you can do something like this https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax("page1.php").done(function(a1) {
    if (a1 == "something") { // if 2nd call dependent on results from 1st
        $.ajax("page2.php").done(function(a2) {
        }).fail(function() {
            // handle with grace
        });
    }
}).fail(function() {
    // handle with grace
});
```