# API check function

Tags: node.js, api, http, express, axios

I am trying to create an IF statement that checks for results from this to API call functions and exits when it returns results.

```
function fetchYelp() {
let token = '<token>';
axios.get('https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=Church on the rock&location=saint peters, MO 63376',{
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    }
})
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

}

fetchYelp();

```
function fetchWhitePages() {
axios.get('https://proapi.whitepages.com/3.0/business?api_key=<apiKey>&address.city=Saint Peters&address.country_code=US&address.postal_code=63376&name=Church on the rock')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

}

fetchWhitePages();

I am drawing a blank.

Comment: I don't see an if statement.

Comment: Hi Kevin, that’s the part that I’m struggling to make sense.  I want to pass in these two api calls in an if statement but exit when it finds a result

Comment: So... you want to make two requests, and then use the result of the two requests in an if statement?

Comment: @KevinB I want pass in the Yelp api ca first, if it returns results, then I want to exit and not make the whitePages call?  If yelp does not return results, I want the next function api call run (whitePages)

Comment: So something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141247/multiple-ajax-posts-in-a-serial-manner

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currently you're not `return`ing anything, you simply just log the data on function call.

Here's an example:

```
function fetchYelp() {
  let token = '<token>';

    axios.get('https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=Church on the rock&location=saint peters, MO 63376',{
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.data) {
        // you should do something here so that you know there's no data, but returning here would exit out
        return;
      };

      return res.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
};
```

ESNext with async/await:

```
async fetchYelp() {
  let token = '<token>';

  try {
    const res = await axios.get('https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=Church on the rock&location=saint peters, MO 63376',{
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    })

    if (!res.data) {
      // again return something here, i'm just using an empty object as an example
      return {};
    }

    return res.data
  } catch (err) {
    // throw can also be treated similar to a return statement
    throw new Error(err)
  }

}
```

Comment: I have a fetchYelp and fetchWhitePages function.   Your thinking I could insert my second function under if and return data?

Comment: @Chris, if the fetch is fairly similar, you can make it really generic and modular so that fetchYelp and fetchWhitePages can have the same functionality.

Comment: when you return the data ( such as return;), how can i retrieve it?

Comment: @Chris well you can't if there's nothing to return. My `if` statement checks to see if any data is already existing, if not return something empty to complete the invocation of the function.

Comment: is there a way to check if the API return array is empty, to move on to the next api call?  such as if(res.data.<arrayIsEmpty>)

Comment: @Chris what about `res.data.length`? like `if (res.data.length < 1)` then trigger the next api call

Comment: this sort of work, takes me to my next task, thank you!